# What is the permission needed for a SQL Server login to change a tables name?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am building out my database using EF Core 2.1 code first migrations. I have altered a table to rename. The migration initially dropped the entire table and then read it with the new name, which had issues with foreign key constraints. I changed the migration to use the `RenameTable` method instead like

```
migrationBuilder.RenameTable("TourSpecs", "TourSpecHistory");
```

When running `update-database` I get the error

> Failed executing DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   DECLARE @defaultSchema sysname = SCHEMA_NAME();
>   EXEC(N'ALTER SCHEMA ' + @defaultSchema + N' TRANSFER [TourSpecHistory].[TourSpecs];');
>   fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
>   Failed executing DbCommand (27ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   DECLARE @defaultSchema sysname = SCHEMA_NAME();
>   EXEC(N'ALTER SCHEMA ' + @defaultSchema + N' TRANSFER [TourSpecHistory].[TourSpecs];');
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object 'TourSpecs', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>   ClientConnectionId:332393e8-8539-4c80-b24c-6478ec61b55b
>   Error Number:15151,State:1,Class:16
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object 'TourSpecs', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   ClientConnectionId:332393e8-8539-4c80-b24c-6478ec61b55b
>   Error Number:15151,State:1,Class:16
>   Cannot find the object 'TourSpecs', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Thinking this is just a permissions issue I ran the command

```
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA:: [dbo].[TourSpec] TO ApplicationLogin
```

But was hit with the error

> Cannot find the schema 'dbo.TourSpec', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

The login I am using to run the grant script has the `ALTER ANY SCHEMA` permission. What do I need to do to get the correct permissions granted to my `ApplicationLogin` user?

Comment: Well...."dbo.TourSpec" is not your schema name. The schema is dbo. If you want only the object you would grant alter on the object, not the schema.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you need to understand [what a sql server schema is](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+what+is+a+schema) ?

Comment: @Igor yep, I'd always heard the tables in shops I worked at referred to as "schemas" by themselves. Looks like I misunderstood the names

Answer (score 1):

After @Sean Lange pointed out that I had an incorrect understanding of what was a schema and what an object, I successfully granted the permissions to my user but was still unable to run the migration. Looking through the `RenameTable` method further, I discovered that it takes in 3 optional arguments at the end and that the migration was incorrectly try to alter a `[TourSpecHistory].[TourSpecs]` table.

I changed the migration to run `migrationBuilder.RenameTable("TourSpecs", "dbo", "TourSpecHistory", "dbo");` and it now works correctly